# Pandas: count cumulated unique string values per group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a question regarding groupby, but I want to groupby period of time in such time period and compute the size of "item" (1month, 2month, 3month).

For example, the data shown below:

```
group    time      item
1      9/30/2014      a
1      10/30/2014     a
1      11/30/2014     b
2      9/30/2014      c
2      10/30/2014     d
2      11/30/2014     d
```

I would like to use the groupby as the time goes to sum the size of the item

```
group    time      item   want
1      9/30/2014      a     1 (because we only have "a" in 9/30/2014 )
1      10/30/2014     a     1 (because we only have "a" from 9/30/2014 to 10/30/2014)
1      11/30/2014     b     2 (because we have "a" and "b" from 9/30/2014 to 11/30/2014)
2      9/30/2014      c     1  
2      10/30/2014     d     2
2      11/30/2014     d     2
```

I appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your periods of time and group are confounded, can you give an example where this is not the case? Or do you consider the dates are already set as consecutive months per group?

Comment: Yes, they are already set as consecutive months

Comment: OK then try [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70966456/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a `groupby` + `expanding` with a `nunique` count.

You need to cheat a bit as `expanding` currently only supports numerical values. So I `factorized` the data first:

```
df['want'] = (
 pd.Series(df['item'].factorize()[0], index=df.index)
   .groupby(df['group'])
   .expanding()
   .apply(lambda s: s.nunique())
   .droplevel(0)
   .astype(int)
 )
```

Output:

```
  group        time item  want
0     a   9/30/2014    a     1
1     a  10/30/2014    a     1
2     a  11/30/2014    b     2
3     b   9/30/2014    c     1
4     b  10/30/2014    d     2
5     b  11/30/2014    d     2
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I am wondering I do not see how you apply the time?

Comment: There is no need to. As you answered to my question, they are already consecutive months ;)